# Save belongs_to ID in a form, without using a hidden field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to work out the best way to save a belongs_to record ID, whilst creating a new child record. I am currently using a hidden field to retain the parent's ID.

**Can you think of a better way to accomplish this save of the parent's ID (without using a hidden field)?**

Here'a a snippet of my routes...

```rb
resources :kids
resources :parents do
  resources :kids
end
```

Here's my parent model...

```rb
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :kids
end
```

Here's my kid model...

```rb
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :parent, :autosave => true
end
```

Here's my view's form when creating a new kid...

```rb
<%= form_for(@kid) do |f| %>
%= f.hidden_field :parent_id, :value => @parent.id %>
<%= f.label :title, 'Title' %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Which then gets passed to the create (POST) method...

```rb
def create
    @kid = Kid.new(params[:kid])
    @parent = Parent.find(@kid.parent_id)
    @kid.save
    # etc...
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you drop the first line of your routes example, to just

```
resources :parents do
  resources :kids
end
```

Now you don't have the ambiguity of calling the KidsController without a parent. Your route match behaves like

```
/parents/:parent_id/kids
```

Now, in your KidsController, you can do

```
def create
  @parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id])
  @parent.kids.create( params[:kid] )
  #...
end
```

The new kid gets its parent auto assigned when you create it via the has_many collection

Answer (score 1):

Yes Nested resources is one of the good way but in your case you can also use "field_for".

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into this

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass it in as a hidden field, I'd recommend using [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), you could keep the `parent_id` in the URL and have `parents/1/kids` as your path.  Then, in the `KidsController`, you'll need to load your parent resource and associate it with the `Kid`